# Open a config file from a folder and update a value (version number of a dll) in C#

Tags: c#, web-config, config

My requirement is, i want to open config file(s) under a folder and change the version number(value) of an entry in it. Version number here is the project dll version of our another component.
What is the best approach to achieve this? please suggest.

TIA!

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar issue. We ended up using post-build events to update the config file. If you are using Visual Studio, you can access post-build events by right clicking on a project, clicking Properties, and going to the Build Events tab.

You can launch a .bat file during the post-build events that will snoop out what the dll version is and then insert it into the config file.

Comment: thank you for the reply. We have many projects in single solution. Said that, there are around 7 to 10 solutions to be implemented. In order to manually update the version every time during Prod deployment, we are thinking to automate it.